# Ionic 5 - Pre select multiple options in ion-select field

Tags: html, angular, ionic-framework, angular9, ionic5

**How to pre-select multiple options in ionic-select-option?**

**NgModel and select no longer work in Ionic 5, so all previous solutions do not work anymore**

There's an array of user's favourite foods that I get from an api,

**User's FavFood Data (userFavFoods)**

```
[
  'apple', 'pear'
]
```

I have an ion-select element that needs to display a user's favourite food and it should be pre-selected so they can unselect it and send off the user's updated favourite foods. This is all in an NgForm.

**Fav Foods html**

```
<form #form="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="submitFavFood(form)" novalidate>
    <ion-select multiple="true" cancelText="Cancel" okText="Ok"  required="true" #food="ngModel" name="foods" placeholder="0 Items" ngModel>
      <ion-select-option *ngFor="let foods of userFavFoods"
                                 value="{{ foods }}">
                {{ foods }}
      </ion-select-option>
    </ion-select>
</form>
```

Other solutions [Ionic 4 pre select ion-select-option](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ion-select-and-default-values-ionic-4-solved/177550/7) do not work for Ionic 5 as both NgModel and Selected aren't supported.

There seems to be solutions using [compareWith]="compareWith", these aren't for multiple section options.

One drastic solution would be to replace the  with checkboxes and ion-text, which means I can programmatically set the checked values.

From inspecting the html, it seems that aria-checked=true when a button is clicked, but adding that to  does not do anything.

Does anyone know if or how pre-selecting ion-select-option with multiple values can be done in Ionic 5?

**EDIT**
It seems that the ion-select docs has an example of pre-selecting values

```
  <ion-item>
    <ion-label>Pets</ion-label>
    <ion-select multiple="true" [value]="['bird', 'dog']">
      <ion-select-option value="bird">Bird</ion-select-option>
      <ion-select-option value="cat">Cat</ion-select-option>
      <ion-select-option value="dog">Dog</ion-select-option>
      <ion-select-option value="honeybadger">Honey Badger</ion-select-option>
    </ion-select>
  </ion-item>
```

**EDIT EDIT**

See my answer below

Answer (score 3):

In .ts file you should declare the default value of that selection as below.

```
foodSelected = ['apple', 'pear'];
foodList = ['apple', 'orange', 'guava', 'pear'];
```

In HTML file add as below.

```
<ion-select multiple="true" [(ngModel)]="foodSelected" [value]="foodSelected">
   <div *ngFor="let food of foodList">
       <ion-select-option value="food">{{food}}</ion-select-option>
   </div>
</ion-select>
```

Comment: For [(ngModel)], I needed to have "foodSelected", not "foodList".

Comment: Yes @AustinV. I updated that. Sorry for the mistake.

Answer (score 3):

The value of an `<ion-select>` when `multiple="true"` is an array of the selected values. So in order to properly preselect one of more values, you can set the value of the `<ion-select>` using `[formcontrol]`.

In the Component:

```
ionSelect: FormControl = new FormControl([]);

ionViewWillEnter() {
     this.ionSelect.setValue(['apple', 'banana']);
}
```

HTML:

```
<ion-select [formControl]="ionSelect" multiple="true" cancelText="Nah" okText="Okay!">
    <ion-select-option value="apple">Apple</ion-select-option>
    <ion-select-option value="banana">Banana</ion-select-option>
    <ion-select-option value="cherry">Cherry</ion-select-option>
    <ion-select-option value="orange">Orange</ion-select-option>
    <ion-select-option value="strawberry">Strawberry</ion-select-option>
</ion-select>
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use use a separate array for selected items in the .ts file:

```
foodSelectedItems = ['apple', 'pear'];
foodListItems = ['apple', 'orange', 'guava', 'pear'];
```

and inside the .html file you can bind `foodSelectedItems` in `[ngModel]="foodSelectedItems"`  or `[value]="foodSelectedItems"` like this:

```
<ion-select multiple="true" [ngModel]="foodSelectedItems" >
   <div *ngFor="let food of foodListItems">
       <ion-select-option value="food">{{food}}</ion-select-option>
   </div>
</ion-select>
```

or

```
<ion-select multiple="true" [value]="foodSelectedItems">
   <div *ngFor="let food of foodListItems">
       <ion-select-option value="food">{{food}}</ion-select-option>
   </div>
</ion-select>
```

**Note:** Your selected array has a single item and must be a String. Otherwise it's not selected.

In my case, I have inherited data like this:

[Data that I have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HrdIK.png)

[select-input looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DrJ1o.png)

So I manage it in html:

```
<ion-item *ngFor="let expertise of myExpertiseData; let i=index">
      <ion-label>{{expertise.title}}</ion-label>
      <ion-select multiple="true" (ionChange)="onChange($event, i)" [value]="expertise.selectedId">
       
        <ion-select-option value="{{item.Id}}" *ngFor="let item of expertise.data" >{{item.Name}}</ion-select-option>

      </ion-select>
    </ion-item>
```

Maybe this helps those that have the data stored like me.

Answer (score 1):

You should use your selection list to [(ngModel)] and selected value list to [value]

Answer (score 0):

It seems I must of checked the previous solutions wrong, **[ngModel]** does work in Ionic 5

```
<form #form="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="submitFavFood(form)" novalidate>
    <ion-select multiple="true" [ngModel]="userFavFoods" cancelText="Cancel" okText="Ok"  required="true" #food="ngModel" name="foods" placeholder="0 Items">
      <ion-select-option *ngFor="let foods of userFavFoods"
                                 value="{{ foods }}">
                {{ foods }}
      </ion-select-option>
    </ion-select>
</form>
```

Above will select all items in the array userFavFoods, aka everything.